# Objective-C XML Parsing

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing

I'm using this code to parse XML in the instance variable `response`:

```
@implementation Delegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
MKFacebook *fbConnection = [[MKFacebook facebookWithAPIKey:@"----" delegate:self] retain];
[fbConnection login];

NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
MKFacebookRequest *request = [MKFacebookRequest requestWithDelegate:self];

//set up parameters for request
[parameters setValue:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[fbConnection uid], @"123456789", nil] forKey:@"uids"];
[parameters setValue:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"first_name",@"last_name",nil] forKey:@"fields"];

//send the request
[request sendRequest:@"users.getInfo" withParameters:parameters];
}


-(void)userLoginSuccessful
{
NSLog(@"neat");
}


- (void)facebookRequest:(MKFacebookRequest *)request responseReceived:(NSString *)response
{
CFStringRef response = (CFStringRef)response;
NSData *xmlData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response2 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData] autorelease];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];     
}
```

But, I am getting this console error upon executing the code:

```
2010-08-12 20:24:46.924 App[2966:a0f] -[NSXMLDocument dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x47c250
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are implementing the delegate method incorrectly.  According to the [MKAbeFook documentation](http://pointlesscrap.net/sites/mkabefook/documentation/090/Protocols/MKFacebookRequestDelegate.html#facebookRequest:responseReceived:), the signature should be:

```
- (void)facebookRequest:(MKFacebookRequest *)request responseReceived:(id)response
```

where `response` is an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` if you specified JSON response type.  Since you seem to be getting an `NSXMLDocument`, it must be defaulting to XML response type.  The XML is already parsed and turned in to a DOM, so you don't need to parse it.  Just cast the response and go to work with the [NSXML tree-based API](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSXMLDocument *document = (NSXMLDocument *)response;
NSArray *someChildren = [document nodesForXPath:@"//foo" error:NULL];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:

1. It's unnecessary to `alloc`/`init` a new data object.  You can simply do:
   `NSXMLParser *parser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:response] autorelease];`
2. Put a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw` and find out where that exception (the unrecognized selector) is coming from.

Comment: it says it coming from [parser parse]; any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that xmlData isn't being initialized properly (I think):

```
NSData *xmlData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:(id)response];
```

For some reason you're casting `response` as an id. `initWithData` expects to be passed an NSData object, therefore you should convert `response` to an NSData (which is currently an NSString) with something like:

```
NSData *xmlData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Have you stepped through it with Gdb? I don't think that code above is your problem, do you have a line number, so you're sure?

Comment: 'Variable is not a CFString', any idea what that means?
http://skitch.com/james-eggers/dt3yk/error

Comment: perhaps whatever is calling that method is sending a CFString and not an NSString? Post more code above going back a few steps.